# Using App Engine Libraries in Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Is there any convenient way I could utilize GAE's libraries in a django project such importing the remote_api_stub?

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
```

I find myself in need to use the remote api within a django app and I'm not sure how to go about fetching the necessary code :/

I've pip installed `appengine` but can't seem to import it into the `settings.py` for some reason...

Comment: Are you running your app in Google App Engine or the local development sdk? The libraries won't work outside of those two environments.

Comment: Oh... so I can't access the remote API (datastore of an app engine app) from a django application? I'm trying to migrate an entire database over from App Engine over to a django based project on AWS.

Comment: Could I authenticate and access the Remote API using the standalone?

Comment: I gave you the wrong link, this is the correct one https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_python/ and yes you can authenticate and access the datastore using this library in any app.

Comment: Hey again. Is there any good tutorials on how to use that? I've been reading the docs here (https://googledatastore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/googledatastore.html#id1) but it's a little scattered.

Comment: I haven't used it so I don't know offhand.

Comment: Alrighty... I'll have to dig around a bit. Thanks for aiming me in the right direction!

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to use the Remote API from a django application? There really isn't any good documents on how to interact with Datastore from a python app.